# Persistent stopwatch that can be paused/unpaused in flutter

Tags: flutter

My flutter app allows users to time how long they have been working for. I'm using the package [stop_watch_timer](https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer).

Everything works fine except when the app gets killed in the background, because then I lose the timer value and it goes back to 0. As users are likely to start the timer then put their phone away and work for a while, the app getting killed is a very likely scenario and I need to make sure that this never happens. Another feature that I need in the app is for users to be able to pause and unpause the timer whenever they want.

Here are the solutions I have come up with so far and their problems:

- Solution 1: Store the start `DateTime` on the phone using `shared_preferences` and calculate the current timer value when app is reopened by simply calculating the duration between start time and `DateTime.now()`. But then I realised that this does not work if the user had paused and unpaused the timer at some point.
- Solution 2: Store the current timer value as a `RestorableInt`. This works if the timer is on pause when the app gets killed, but does not work if the timer is meant to be running when the app dies.

Any suggestions or ideas??

Comment: when your app gets killed store current timer and the datetime the app was killed (only if the status is active, not paused) - that's enough

Comment: @pskink how would I get the datetime the app was killed?

Comment: `DateTime.now()`

Comment: @pskink no I mean how can I get `DateTime.now()` at the moment the app is killed?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState.html

Comment: @pskink Which one is better to use `AppLifecycleState.paused` or `AppLifecycleState.detached`?? And how reliable are these?

Comment: i don't know how reliable they are - the docs say: "Applications should not expect to always receive all possible notifications"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store something like this:

```json
[
{"start":1664027960},
{"pause":1664027975},
{"unpause":1664027979},
{"pause":1664028061},
{"unpause":1664028065},
]
```

Everytime a user hits the pause button you add the time to the list and store it in the shared_prefs or in a json file. Same for unpausing.

You can then calculate the total ellapsed time.